# Issue with saving HTML canvas conent using phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas

I have have one HTML canvas where I can do signature, For saving the canvas content I have used the plugin from the following URL,

https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

After using this plugin, I have one issue i.e, The image is saving to phone's gallery but the image is blank image that is just a black screen. Th canvas content is not saving. How can we get the canvas content and save it in the phone's gallery?

Script:

var sigCapture;

```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   function onDeviceReady()
     {
      $(document).ready(function() {
         sigCapture = new SignatureCapture( "signature" );
      });
     }


   function saveCanvas()
   {
      window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
                function(msg){
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                },
                document.getElementById('signature')
            );
   } 

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div  data-role="page" id="personalinfo">
            <div  data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">                                    
                  <h4>SBI Account Open</h4>                                    
               </div>

                  <h2>SIGNATURE</h2>
           <div id="canvasContainer"  >
                   <canvas id="signature" />
           </div>
           <button  onClick='saveCanvas()'>Start</button>
   </div>
```

Can anyone help me how to save the canvas content i.e, signature

Comment: Image is saving but It doesn't capture the signature. Only blank image (black screen) is saving. How to save signature?

Comment: Guess the base64 decoding and removal of data URI info in the string is not done correctly, hence corrupting the image data

Answer (score 0):

I'm flying blind here, since don't have how to test it right now, but: canvas its not a self closing tag. Try changint it to `<canvas id="signature"></canvas>`